# How to customize Google Pay's payment sheet?

Tags: android, google-pay

I want to customize the Google Pay payment sheet UI to display additional data (such as Card Billing address, city, country, postal code ...).

[image]

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: as to your question, i have honestly no idea if it's possible to edit the payment sheet/dialog, i don't think it is though, but i could be entirely wrong. i've only ever used the default one provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to display billing address/details in the payment sheet. Billing details are attached to the user's chosen payment method so they don't really have the option to choose different billing details.

It would be interesting to understand your use case for displaying billing address is. If you want it for shipping, then I would suggest using [`shippingAddressRequired`](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/request-objects#PaymentDataRequest) instead.